# Is there a QGIS plugin that can transform tabular data to graph?

Tags: qgis, plugins

I have a CSV file with water level measurments in a well, taken once a year for 40 years. 
Is there a way to show this data as a graph (x axis being the date and y axis the water level) in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to produce the graph using QGIS? I would suggest using R (free software) or excel.

**in R:**

go to file / change dir... and navigate to the folder with your csv

code:

```
data = read.csv("yourdata.csv")
x <- data$date
y <- data$waterlevel
plot(x,y)
?plot
```

If you need to display the graph in QGIS you can save the image as a TIFF from R and import it into QGIS.

Comment: I have hunderds of wells but need only the one closest to the site I'm working on. So selecting the closest wells in QGIS is very simple. 
I can copy the data of those specific wells to Excell, but thought maybe there's a plugin in QGIS that creates such a graph.

Comment: Check out the TimeSeriesPlot plugin in the QGIS User-Contributed Python Plugin Repository, it might serve your purposes.