# Is there a way to create layer summary Pie Charts?

Tags: qgis, diagram

In Qgis2.6. I want to create a pie chart to summarize the layer data. I have a layer of land use polygons (woodland, agricultural, urban etc.). I want a pie chart to show the % of each land use in the layer.
I see the diagrams section of layer properties will provide pie charts for each polygon, and the 'Group Stats' plugin will calculate the totals I need. All tantalizingly close.
Does anyone know of a way this can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a QGIS plugin that can transform tabular data to graph?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122405/is-there-a-qgis-plugin-that-can-transform-tabular-data-to-graph)

Comment: As indicated at other questions, it appears QGIS does not currently have a graphing (charting) tool such as the one found in ArcGIS. Your best bet may be to get the stats you need as a table, export it, and then create the chart in something else like Excel or R.